# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alert", "alert('Ouve algum problema nos itens " + text + "');", true);
```

where text is a string as I am trying to insert a `\n` in the text message but does not show any.

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alert", "alert('Ouve algum problema nos itens " + text + "');", true);

Comment: Ouve quer dizer que alguém ouviu, escutou. Houve quer dizer que algo aconteceu ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code text needs two escape thingies.

```
string text = "test \\n testing";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alert", "alert('Ouve algum problema nos itens " + text + "');", true);
```

use:

```
string text = "test \\n testing";
```

Instead of:

```
string text = "test \n testing";
```

Comment: no problem, the single one will create a new line break in your html code ("view source code"). and the double one will bring it to the user.

Comment: I just spent an entire day trying to figure out why my `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` wasn't working properly either and then I came across this while writing out my own question. Does it make a difference if you do `"alert('Ouve algum problema nos itens test \n testing');"` With the `\n` in the main argument string instead of putting it into a `string` variable?

Answer (score 0):

The `", True"` adds the script tags.

You want `GetType(Page)`